# no module named textblob (on a mac)

Tags: python, python-3.x, textblob

I have been trying to install textblob on my mac but I keep getting errors.

I followed the instructions here https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob

for installing the packaged 
I ran the lines

```
$ pip install -U text blob
```

in which my terminal returned

```
Requirement already up-to-date: textblob in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: nltk>=3.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from textblob)
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from nltk>=3.1->textblob
```

)

Then following I ran

```
$ python3 -m textblob.download_corpora
```

in which my computer returned

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'textblob.download_corpora' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textblob')
```

I looked at this post [Unable to get up and running with TextBlob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174482/unable-to-get-up-and-running-with-textblob) and made sure i had no files named text or textblob so now i am at a wall not knowing what else to do. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

You might have a broken link between textblob and the version of Python.

Try running:

```
python -m pip install -U textblob
```

Answer (score 1):

TextBlob is also available as a conda package. To install with conda, run

```
$ conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/sloria textblob
$ python -m textblob.download_corpora
```