# Error while installing textblob through conda on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, conda, ubuntu-18.04, textblob

I tried

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge textblob
```

and

```
$ python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

following [this link](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/install.html), but I am getting the following error-

```
Error while finding module specification for 'textblob.download_corpora' (AttributeError: module 'textblob' has no attribute '__path__')
```

Can someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have used Python-3.x tag so I consider that you have Python3 installed with anaconda but you've used **python -m textblob.download_corpora**. This is a possible issue: https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues/197

Try the following command

```
$ python3 -m textblob.download_corpora
```

Also, if you still get the error, follow [this](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/install.html) link for following commands in Ubuntu:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob.git
$ python3 setup.py install
```

Moreover, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026298/no-module-named-textblob-on-a-mac). Let me know if you still face the issue.